# Combine lists into one numpy array and sum diagonal values

Tags: python, arrays

Hi I want to combine lists into one numpy array. However, it seems that I need to transfer them into arrays first, then combine them into a bigger array.
I just wonder can I combine lists into an array directly.

```
The lists
[1,2,3,4,5]
[6,7,8,9,10]
[11,12,13,14,15]
[1,2,3,4,5]
[6,7,8,9,10]
```

I want to combine them into an 5*5 array

```
array(
[[1,2,3,4,5],
[6,7,8,9,10],
[11,12,13,14,15],
[1,2,3,4,5],
[6,7,8,9,10]])
```

After getting the array, I want to sum the array's diagonal values, which is 6+2+13+9+5. Therefore I want to make sure the array format can let me do `np.diag` as well.

Comment: you mean diagonal?

Comment: `np.row_stack`?

Comment: @BanishedBot yes thank you, I've edited the question

Comment: how are the lists stored?

Comment: `numpy.array`'s constructor will accept a `list` of `list`s of number and make a 2-D matrix out of it.  What do you mean by "need[ing] to transfer them into arrays first"?  Could you post your code?

Comment: 6+2+13+9+5? That would be when the lists are arranged in a different order I guess, otherwise is not the diagonal of the 2D array.

Comment: @dan04 I've combined the lists into an array by using np.row_stack

Comment: @b-fg Yes you are right, I need to stack the lists by reversed order for getting the diagonal values I want. Just wonder is there any better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However, you are going to convert the list to an array to perform `np.diag` on it.
So, hope you can do the same as you mentioned in the post, as like below:

```
import numpy as np
k=np.array([[6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5],[11,12,13,14,15],[6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5]])
print(k)
>>array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
           [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
           [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
           [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
           [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5]])
np.diag(k)
>>array([ 6,  2, 13,  9,  5])
sum(np.diag(k))
>>35
```

You can refer to [asarray()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html#numpy.asarray) method. But, its again equivalent to doing the above.